# Send multiple kill signals to a process

Tags: process, kill, signal

Say I run a `.sh` process. And now I open a new terminal tab and I want to send signals to it, for that, I just use kill:

```
kill -*signal number* *pid*
```

right? But I want to send 13 signals at the same time, how can I do that?

Comment: 13 different signals or the same signal 13 times?

Comment: @PerlDuck 13 different signals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot send 13 signals at once but must loop over some list of signals. The following script will do so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pid=${1-""}

if [ -z "$pid" ]; then
    echo "a pid must be given";
    exit 1;
fi

siglist=(
    SIGSTOP SIGCONT SIGSTOP SIGCONT SIGSTOP SIGCONT
    SIGSTOP SIGCONT SIGSTOP SIGCONT SIGSTOP SIGCONT
    SIGTERM
)

for sig in "${siglist[@]}"; do
    kill -$sig $pid;
done

exit 0;
```

Save the script as `send-sigs.sh`, apply `chmod +x send-sigs.sh` and then call it like so:

```
./send-sigs.sh 1234
```

I used the signals STOP and CONT to alternately *freeze* and *thaw* the given pid but you can use different signals to your liking. But be aware that some signals might stop your target process so it won't receive any signals afterwards.